# com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception occurred while reading the license file

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

The error is occurring when a Batch Server logs in to the Google Cloud Storage to search for files in the Google Cloud Storage.

The Batch Server logs in using the cloud client credentials that is stored as a json file, but the error occurs, saying:

```
Caused by: com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception occurred while reading the license file.
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException.translateAndThrow(StorageException.java:81)
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.get(StorageImpl.java:332)
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.get(StorageImpl.java:338)
at com.telus.equipmentmgt.handler.gcloud.impl.GcpClientImpl.getFileContent(GcpClientImpl.java:73)
... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception occurred while reading the license file.
at weblogic.security.utils.SSLSetup.getLicenseLevel(SSLSetup.java:143)
at weblogic.security.utils.SSLSetup.getSSLDelegateInstance(SSLSetup.java:196)
at weblogic.security.utils.SSLContextWrapper.<init>(SSLContextWrapper.java:27)
at weblogic.security.utils.SSLContextWrapper.getInstance(SSLContextWrapper.java:22)
at weblogic.security.utils.SSLSetup.getSSLContext(SSLSetup.java:380)
at weblogic.security.SSL.SSLClientInfo.getSSLSocketFactory(SSLClientInfo.java:56)
at weblogic.security.SSL.SSLSocketFactory.setSSLClientInfo(SSLSocketFactory.java:218)
at weblogic.security.SSL.SSLSocketFactory.<init>(SSLSocketFactory.java:36)
at weblogic.security.SSL.SSLSocketFactory.getInstance(SSLSocketFactory.java:68)
at weblogic.net.http.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:561)
at weblogic.net.http.HttpsURLConnection.connect(HttpsURLConnection.java:242)
at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:235)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:113)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1012)
at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:441)
at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refresh(OAuth2Credentials.java:160)
at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getRequestMetadata(OAuth2Credentials.java:147)
at com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter.initialize(HttpCredentialsAdapter.java:91)
at com.google.cloud.http.HttpTransportOptions$1.initialize(HttpTransportOptions.java:159)
```

This is how we read the files in the Google Cloud Storage:

```
`public String getFileContent(String fileName, String directory, CardDistribConnDtl rkFtpConnInfo) throws FtpClientHandlerException {
 String projectId = (String)rkFtpConnInfo.getUserId();
 String cloudClientCredentialPath = (String)rkFtpConnInfo.getPasswordStr();
 String bucketName = rkFtpConnInfo.getHostNmStr();
 try {
 Storage storage = getStorage(projectId, cloudClientCredentialPath);
 BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, directory + "/" + fileName);
 Blob blob = storage.get(blobId);
 if (blob != null) {
 ReadChannel reader = blob.reader();
 BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(Channels.newInputStream(reader)); 
 String content = IOUtils.toString(bis); 
 return content;
 } else {
 throw new FtpClientHandlerException("blob for " + directory + "/" + fileName + " is null");
 }
 } catch(Exception ex) {
 throw new FtpClientHandlerException(FtpClientHandlerException.E3006_ftp_failed_to_get_remote_file, "unable to get file content from remote", ex);
 }
}
private Storage getStorage(String projectId, String keyFilePath) throws FtpClientHandlerException {

 try {

 GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(keyFilePath));

 Builder builder = StorageOptions.newBuilder();
 builder.setProjectId(projectId).setCredentials(credentials);
 StorageOptions storageOptions = builder.build();
 Storage storage = storageOptions.getService();
 return storage;

 } catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
 throw new FtpClientHandlerException(FtpClientHandlerException.E3008_ftp_invalid_login_credentials, "unable to locate cloud client credential", ex);
 } catch(IOException ex) {
 throw new FtpClientHandlerException(FtpClientHandlerException.E3008_ftp_invalid_login_credentials, "unable to read from cloud client credential", ex);
 } catch(Exception ex) {
 throw new FtpClientHandlerException(FtpClientHandlerException.E3008_ftp_invalid_login_credentials, "unable to get storage connection", ex);
 }
}
```

Whenever I restart the batch server, the batch server successfully reads the files in the Google Cloud Storage, but only this time (whenever we upload new files in the GCS, the error above already occurs).

Why is the google client logged in already seems to be losing the "license" or "authentication" to read the new files uploaded in the Google Cloud Storage? Does the Cloud Storage's token authentication resets, that's why the existing token the Batch Server used is not valid anymore?